# Grep IP addresses with only 1 digit in the first octet

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I am trying to output all IPs in a file with 1 digit in the first octet.

The file structure:
1.56.46.44
244.34.56.90
198.168.1.1
etc...

And I am looking for just the output of
1.56.46.44

I have tried:

```
 grep -E "[^^][0-9].[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}" file.txt
```

which outputs every IP highlighting only a few numbers

and also have tried:

```
  grep -o -n '\b[0-9].' file.txt
```

which outputs any one digit octet

Comment: You need to escape all the `.` characters.

Comment: `grep -E '^[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$' file.txt`

Comment: What are you trying to do with `[^^]`?  That does not match beginning of line, but any character that is not `^`.

Comment: If your input is well formatted (eg, all lines are an ipv4 address), you could probably get away with `grep -e '^[0-9]\.'` or even just `grep -e '^.\.'`

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape the `.` characters, otherwise they match anything, including another digit.

And you shouldn't have `[^^]` at the beginning. That matches any character other than `^`. So if the input starts with `12.`, the `1` will be matched by `[^^]`. Use `^` by itself to match the beginning of the line.

```
grep -E '^[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$' file.txt
```

Comment: I was able to use- grep -e '^[0-9]\.' file.txt